# Show Modal From dynamically inserted button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a table element :

```
<table id="postcon-table-success" class="table table-hover">
</table>
```

and I am inserting rows dynamically in the table:

```
postConTable = "<tr><td><input id=\""+value.processId+"-details\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary view-details\" value=\"View Details\" /></td></tr>";
$("#postcon-table-success").append(postConTable);
```

here button has id as dynamic variable (processID) followed by "-value"
eg.230002-details, where 230002 is processID.

Now I am clicking the button

```
$('#postcon-table-running').on('click',".view-details", function() {   
   console.log(this.id);
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

which is calling the jquery function and the log is getting printed :
230002-details

But its not showing the modal which is in the body tag.

```
<body id="fixedbody" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar">
   <div id="master-container" class="container-fluid">
      <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Please wait</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p>We are fetching data</p>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Please help.

To ADD- when I create my modal in the parent tag of '#postcon-table-running', it is working.
But I cant do it that way because I want to implement same functionaliy from various buttons in various other divs.

Comment: do you see the modal html using firebug or page source? do you get errors in your error console?

Comment: Table rows are appended to `#postcon-table-success` but click handling is delegated to `#postcon-table-running`. Are you sure that's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the modal is not visible to the on click function.  Put your modal at the very end of the page.